# Ошибка php init в yii2

Tags: инициализация, права-доступа

При попытке инициализации yii2-advanced в терминале ошибка:
Error. Operation chmod not permitted for directory backend/runtime.

Error. Operation chmod not permitted for directory backend/web/assets.

Error. Operation chmod not permitted for directory console/runtime.

Error. Operation chmod not permitted for directory frontend/runtime.

Error. Operation chmod not permitted for directory frontend/web/assets.
При том, что права доступа на все папки 777

Comment: точно? попробуй `sudo chmod 777 -R backend/web/assets` и другие

Answer (score 0):

Кому интересно, нужно переназначить владельца папки с рута на Ваш:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www